# Display relative containers (with variable height) below each other

Tags: css, position, css-position

I have some relatively positioned containers (that vary in height) and I want to display them under each other. What's happening is they are displaying on top of each other (see fiddle).

I am using `position:relative` on the containers because I want the child elements to have `position:absolute` and display relative to their container. I think there is probably a quick fix with a fixed height for example but that isn't very flexible, my containers (or their children) will vary in height.

[Desired result - fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHA3b/)

[Actual result - fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erZcE/)

Code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.outside
{
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.inside
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
</style>

<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside"><p>absolute 1</p></div>
</div>
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside"><p>absolute 2</p></div>
</div>
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside"><p>absolute 3</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you position something **absolute** inside a **relative** element, this relative element won't take in consideration the width or height of the absolute element, so just add a `height:30px;` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dsaff/) -

If you do not wish to have a fixed height, then use at least a `min-height`. - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dCMcC/) -

Comment: `min-height` will be the same as `height` in this case, because the `outer` div is NOT going to get any taller than the min-height`` setting regardless of the content in the `inside` div.

Comment: The `outer` will get taller if its affected by other `non absolute` elements, if it needs more than 30px, it will get larger, the `absolute` element won't affect the height of the `outer`, but I'm sure that the `absolute` element won't be the only element inside those divs..

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I may have to settle for the fixed height but was hoping for another way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that your `outside` containers have no dimension because the `inside` divs are **absolutely** positioned.

Since you say these are variable height containers, I know of no way to fix this.

What's wrong with the 'desired result' fiddle? It seems that you are trying to recreate the default behavior of how boxes are rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the desired result fiddle doesn't have the relative position, so I can't have absolute positioned child elements that are relative to their container. In reality the child elements vary in height but I just simplified it for the question.

Comment: @ServerBloke Right, but why absolutely position the `inside` DIV? By default it will begin to layout from `left: 0` and `top: 0`.

Comment: The reason I want absolute position on the `inside` is because I will have multiple `inside` elements within a container and I want to stack them on top of eachother so I use `top:0;left:0;` and so if I don't have a relative positioned container, the `inner` elements will not position to `0,0` of their container.